# Traceback (most recent call last): File "None", line 18, in <module> IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
text= open("/Users/amanshah/Desktop/hsn/a.tcp","r")
lines=text.readlines()
a=[]
c=[]
d=[]
e=[]
sum1=0
for line in lines:
    temp=line.split()
    a.append(int(temp[1]))
    c.append(int(temp[5]))
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i]==a[i+1]:
        sum1=sum1+c[i]
        d[i].append(a[i])
        e[i].append(sum)
    else:
        d[i+1].append(a[i])
        e[i+1].append(sum1)
print d
```

print e

## showing error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "None", line 18, in 
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

You are appending to a list element that doesn't exist:

```
d[i+1].append(a[i])
```

This is equivalent to:

```
d = []
d[1].append('a')
```

This will give you the same error.  I don't know what you are trying to put into d and e, but you can append to them, but not to elements of them that don't exist.

It looks like a dictionary would be a better choice for this application.

```
d = {}

if i not in d:
    d[i] = []
d[i].append(a[i])
```

I don't have a full understanding of what you are trying, but this will check to see if this item has been found before.  If not then it will create an empty list to append to.  Then it appends the entry for this.

Comment: i have a 2 list a=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5] and c=[23,34,43,56,3,89,5,67,45,1,11,91,23,40,65,22] elements in array a=[ ] represent port number and c=[ ] represent its corresponding payload soo i am trying to add all the payload corresponding of port no 1 , 2, 4, 5

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though this should be rewritten as something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

INPUT = "/Users/amanshah/Desktop/hsn/a.tcp"

payloads = defaultdict(int)

with open(INPUT) as inf:
    for line in inf:
        values  = line.split()
        port    = int(values[1])
        payload = int(values[5])
        payloads[port] += payload

for port in sorted(payloads):
    print("{}: {}".format(port, payloads[port]))
```

**Edit**: based on your comment above, it looks like you are scanning a tcp log file and adding up total transfer amounts per port.

So I created a dictionary called `payloads` where `payloads[port]` keeps the sum of all payloads for that port; additionally, I made it a `defaultdict(int)`, which just means if I ask for `payloads[port_I_havent_seen_yet]` it automagically creates and returns a new entry == 0 instead of throwing a KeyError.

I then scan through each line of the file, updating `payloads` as I go.

At the end, `sorted(payloads)` gets a list of `payloads`'s keys (all the ports I have encountered) and sorts it in ascending order; I then print out each port and its total payload. Based on your sample data, you should see

```
1: 156
2: 97
4: 124
5: 241
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey hugh did you use the concept of hash mapping in the following code can u just explain wat u did ?

Comment: Thanks a lot mate its working actually my tcp file had 22 lac packets with 3000 ports and its working now.